# Finite rank operators dense in space of linear operators

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $X$ be a Banach space. Let $H\otimes X$ denote the space of finite rank operators from $X$. Every element of $H\otimes X$ can be represented in the from $\sum_{i=1}^N h_i\otimes x_i$ where $h_i\otimes x_i$ denotes the rank one operator defined by $(h_i\otimes x_i)h=\langle h_i,h\rangle x$.

How can one show that $H\otimes X$ is dense in the space of linear operators $L(H,X)$ with respect to the standard operator norm or where is this proven?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't show it because it is false. For instance, consider $X=H$ where $H$ is infinite-dimensional. Then $H \otimes X$ are the finite-rank operators $H \to H$, and their norm-closure is the compact operators.